# Stopping setinterval function in Jquery after loading required page

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I'm using this code below to load external pages into a div. One of the pages has a `setinterval` function for 1 second. when i navigate back to the page the `setinterval` code runs twice and i only want it to run once. how do i stop the interval when i navigate out of that page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').html("");
    $('.content').load($('.john:first').attr('href'));
    $('.john').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.content').html("");
        $('.content').load(href).fadeIn('1000');
        return false;
    });
});
```

the setinterval function in that page looks like this.

```
function loadingstaff (){
    var ids = "";
    $.post("loadfast.php",{id: ids},
    function (data){
        $(".getposta").html(data);
    });
}
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(loadingstaff, 1000);
```

Comment: use `clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);`where you need.

Comment: when i use `clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);` it does not work since the click event in not in the same page as the setinterval function

Comment: try it in right after the `setInterval`

Comment: use the `setTimeout` instand of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.john').click(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.content').html("");
    $('.content').load(href).fadeIn('1000');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` insted of `setInterval`. The `setInterval` do the task after the given time recursively, and you need just one time, so the `setTimeout` is best for your purpose.

```
function loadingstaff (){
   var ids = "";
   $.post("loadfast.php",{id: ids},
   function (data){
       $(".getposta").html(data);
   });
 }
var refreshIntervalId = setTimeout(loadingstaff, 1000);
```

Comment: it does not work, the data being loaded after the interval does not appear

Comment: [see this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout), it is identical to your demand.

Comment: so , what you really want?